# How to calculate the total chern classes of CP^n

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, chern-classes

When calculating the total chern class of $\ CP^n$, we use the fact that their is a exact sequence of vector bundles over $\ CP^n$:
$$\ 0\to S \to C^{n+1} \to Q \to 0$$
And identify the bundle $\ TCP^n $ with the bundle $\ Q \otimes S^*$,where $\ S$ is the universal subbundle over $\ CP^n $ and $\ Q $ is the corresponding quotient bundle over $\ CP^n$. But I have no idea why these two bundles are isomorphic to each other. In other words, how to identify the bundle $\ TCP^n $ with the bundle $\ Q \otimes S^*$? Is there any intuitive idea?

Comment: The tangent space at a line tells you how many ways you can wiggle. To wiggle a line in a vector space, you need to say what direction you're wiggling it. So that's like a linear map from your line to the vector space. But if you wiggle in the same direction as the line, then the line didn't move. That's what the exact sequence says.

Comment: (or rather, what I described was an exact sequence like trivial---> O(1)^{\oplus n+1}--->TCP^n, which is what's usually used to do the chern class computation)